# Expression Blend changing Alignment

Tags: expression-blend

Expression Blend 4 is changing the HorizontalAlignment and or VerticalAlignment when moving TextBlock objects with the keyboard or mouse. How can this be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. Its a visual editor, it will generate code depending on how the view looks after you're performed changes. It will create the best code that will match the layout you created based on what it understands.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain when it does that..
Go into the XAML view, and modify it by hand after you're happy everything is the right place and is the correct size, by just changing the Alignments and margins.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the object, you will notice guide bars traveling vertically and horizontally from the object. At the end of these you will see little "chain link" icons. You can click these on and off at either end to toggle the alignment.